# Tab to next tab index after input condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to tab automatically to the next tabindex after a condition is met.  Any idea how I can access the tabindex, without using the id tag of the next element?.

**HTML:**

```
<tr>

<td id = "t3"> <input type="text" id = "ate" oninput="ate()" tabindex= "1" class = "tabable"/> </td>

<td id = "t3"> <input type="text" id = "eaten" oninput ="eaten()" tabindex= "2" class = "tabable" /> </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
function ate(){
var value = document.getElementById("ate").value;
var get_tab = document.getElementById("ate").getAttribute('tabindex');
var next_tab = get_tab + 1 ;

if (value == "ate") {

        $('#ate').fadeTo(1000, 0);
        $('#ate').prop('tabIndex', -1);
        //document.getAttribute('tabindex'); ??     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can select an element with this selector:

```
$('input[tabindex="2"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the next `input` using the classname `.tabable` and add `.focus()`.

**Here is a live example:**

```js
function ate() {
  var value = document.getElementById("ate").value;
  var get_tab = document.getElementById("ate").getAttribute('tabindex');
  var next_tab = get_tab + 1;

  if (value == "ate") {
    $('#ate').fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $('#ate').prop('tabIndex', -1);
    //document.getAttribute('tabindex'); ??  

    $('#ate').next('.tabable').focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td id="t3">
    <input type="text" id="ate" oninput="ate()" tabindex="1" class="tabable" />
  </td>

  <td id="t3">
    <input type="text" id="eaten" oninput="eaten()" tabindex="2" class="tabable" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Ben : Welcome to SO. Happy to help!